# Secure Sql query with many parameters

Tags: mysql, vb.net

When I run this block of code, an message appears saying: "A fatal error occured." Pls tell me whats wrong.

```
Try
    con.Open()
    'Get the sales number from the sales table to confirm when the shoe is sold.
    .CommandText = "SELECT sales.Sales_number, clients.Client_id from sales JOIN clients ON (sales.Serial_number = clients.Serial_number) WHERE sales.Serial_number = @Serial"

    objDataAdapter = New MySqlDataAdapter(.CommandText, con)
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial", strSerial)
    objDataAdapter.Fill(objDataset)
    'Sales number
    strRSerial = objDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString
    strClientID = objDataset.Tables(0).Rows(0).Item(1).ToString


    'Update the shoe in store table to confirm when sales is made 
    'Here we update the table Shoein Store

    .CommandText = "UPDATE `mayombe_mdcs`.`shoesinstore` SET `Sales_number` = @RSerial WHERE Serial_number = @Serial2 ;"
    cmd = New MySqlCommand(.CommandText)
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RSerial", strRSerial)
    objDataAdapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Serial2", strSerial)
    updateResponse1 = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery
       con.close()                    
catch ex as Exception
   MsgBox(ex.message)
end try
```

Comment: I exist in the code. i've just omitted.

Comment: First of all you forgot to close your connection.

Comment: Which line caused error?

Comment: I see at least 6 errors in the code that could cause exceptions.  Without running the code I am not certain the exact exception from the mySQL library.

Comment: Errors in the code you should fix first.

Comment: Errors in the code you should fix first.  1.  You assume that your objDataSet will have a table and a row in ALL cases.  You cannot make this assumption unless you have very very strong business logic preventing those kinds of conditions.  If you call tables(0) and there are no tables, you will crash out to your exception handler.  Same with the Items(0) and Items(1).  If you convert your first query to a datareader format you will get better visibility on any errors and where they might be occurring.

Comment: Also, your code is already wrapped up in an exception handler, thats good, but in this case you need a finally block.  In the finally block you close your connection.  The code you have now when it crashes to the exception handler, the connection remains open.